# What is wrong in this regex code?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to modify my code like below but after modification my regex dont work. what I am doing wrong?

***my code***

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"USER1\"[.](.+)");
richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

***modified code***

```
Regex reg = new Regex(String.Format("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"{0}\"[.](.+)",textbox1.text);

richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

Comment: Is the `{0}` in the rickTextBox1.Text? `{}` are used for defined repeats usually, you could try escaping the braces: `\{0\}`.

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO THIS IS EVEN WORSE THAN CONCATENATION DON'T GENERATE SQL WITH REGEX!!!!

Comment: seconding It'sNotALie, you are heading for **much trouble** if you synthesize sql. the risk of sql injection is just too high, if your code will ever be reviewed, it most certainly will not pass. use prepared statements and host variables instead.

Comment: I dont GENERATE SQL WITH REGEX!!!!.

Comment: hi jerry, your solution \{0\}  gives error each {   } : Unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem with your code stems from the threat of [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This approach of building the sql statement dynamically with string manipulation is frought with danger, using regexes or not.

**STOP NOW**

Your more focused problem goes away.

Use some approach that uses parameters substitution. ADO.Net commands with paramters or an ORM or perhaps write a stored procedure.

Comment: I dont think it nothing to do with SQL injection. it is just a plain sentence that shows on richtextBox

Comment: @user2661591, ok, I see, human assitance is required to perform the attack. Is this just a tool for writing SQL?

Comment: just a tool that writing script like TOYS